# Edit CSS of a plugin

Tags: wp-enqueue-style, wp-register-style

I'd like to edit a CSS file that is located at `wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-gateway-stripe/assets/css/stripe-styles.css`, I tried to overwrite it by placing the edited css in my child theme at `wp-content/themes/flatsome-child/woocommerce-gateway-stripe/assets/css/stripe-styles.css`, does not work.
Second thing I tried is to deregister and dequeque the CSS, in the original plugin it's registered and quequed like this

```
wp_register_style( 'stripe_styles', plugins_url( 'assets/css/stripe-styles.css', WC_STRIPE_MAIN_FILE ), array(), WC_STRIPE_VERSION );
wp_enqueue_style( 'stripe_styles' );
```

I've added this to my functions.php

```
function dequeue_my_css() {
  wp_dequeue_style('wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-gateway-stripe/assets/css/stripe-styles.css');
  wp_deregister_style('wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-gateway-stripe/assets/css/stripe-styles.css');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','dequeue_my_css');
```

But the CSS is still there.
Any ideas what it's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to dequeue an enqueued style you need to use the `wp_dequeue_style()` function with the *handle* of the style you want to remove. The handle is the first argument of `wp_register_style()` and `wp_enqueue_style()`. In your case that's `stripe_styles`.

So if you want to deregister and dequeue it:

```
wp_dequeue_style( 'stripe_styles' );
wp_deregister_style( 'stripe_styles' );
```

You need to make sure this code is run after the original styles were enqueued or nothing will happen. So you need to check the priority of the `wp_enqueue_scripts` hook that was used to register the original styles.

In the plugin the `wp_enqueue_style()` function will have been used inside a function that was hooked into `wp_enqueue_scripts`, so look for the `add_action()` that hooks that function and check the 3rd argument. If it doesn't exist then the priority is `10`, if it does exist the priority is whatever number is there. Make sure your `add_action()` has a higher priority.

Comment: Ty, all good now!